# Draw multiple feeds simultaneously from the Google Feed API

Tags: javascript, rss, google-feed-api

Using the [Google Feed API](https://developers.google.com/feed/) it's possible to request multiple feed objects like so:

```
var feed1 = new google.feeds.Feed(url1),
    feed2 = new google.feeds.Feed(url2),
    feed3 = new google.feeds.Feed(url3);

feed1.load(callback);
feed2.load(callback);
feed3.load(callback);
```

This can create a large number of simultaneous requests that can take a long time to resolve and load.

Is there a way to get multiple feeds from the API and retrieve them with a single request?

Comment: To my knowledge it is not possible, however, that should not be a problem because jabascript is async, so you cn certainly make multiple requests in parallel, and, based on the number of conurrent connections allowed by your browser, you'll get responses simultaneously!

Comment: You are correct, but I was hoping to avoid this behavior as requesting more simultaneous feeds than the browser has concurrent connections is the source of the slow loading I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Another way would then be to use different services or even services with different subdomains because the conucurrency limits in browsers is domain/subdomains based. You could "cheat" when using a service like [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com) by proxying calls to its api thru different domains on your end.

Answer (score 2):

The [API developer guide](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide) doesn't seem to have an option to allow that, so I'd guess you need to do it the way you are using it currently, although IMO it may be a better idea to request them one after another to not overload the server.